# Outlook send from different email address not working on terminal server

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, exchange

I am trying to set up users so that they can chose which of their email addresses they can send out as. 
On PCs, I add account a second time using pop3 and it then gives you the option of which account to show as when you're sending an email. Everything works fine and the recipient correctly sees the chosen account address.

This does not seem to work correctly on our terminal servers. It lets me add the account and when you're sending an email, it says it's going to send it via the second account's email address. However, when it gets delivered it is still showing up using the original account's email address.

The outlook client is fully updated and matches between the PC and the terminal server (2007 - 12.0.6691.5000), exchange server is running 2013. 
What could be causing this to not work correct from TS (running on win server 2003)?

Comment: Any GPO rules on the terminal server that could affect Outlook usage?

Comment: No, it shouldn't be any of our GPO rules. As a domain admin the only setting in the policy that get applied to me set the roaming profile / folder redirection and time limits.